# $(...)..map(...).reduce is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to calculate the sum of the height of a couple elements in the page using map & reduce. For unknown reasons this is throwing me the following exception:

> VM52933:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).map(...).reduce is not a
>   function(…)

```
$('.items')
    .map( (index,slide) => $(slide).height() )
    .reduce( (prev, next) => prev + next, 0 )
```

.map returns a valid array:

```
[48, 48, 48, 75, 48]
```

If i do the map separately ( **[48, 48, 48, 75, 48].reduce(...)** ) it works.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Add `.get()` between the `map` and `reduce`. Otherwise you have a jQuery object containing an array.

Comment: can you post a small example with `.items` here in the fiddle?

Comment: That's because [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method returns **jQuery object**, not array.

Comment: jQuery-objects are lists, but they ain't Arrays. And `reduce` is a method of Array

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solution. It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is because you are when you do $('.items') its an array like structure but not array. If you see the prototype it dof NodeList type ad it doesn't have reduce method on it. If you pass this from Array.from then it will convert it to proper array and you will be able to apply reduce, map and all the other array functions.

More details can be found at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

do something like

```
Array.from($('.items'))
.map( (slide) => $(slide).height() )
.reduce( (prev, next) => prev + next, 0 );
```

Comment: For some reason this solution is returning me '0'. adding .get() between .map() and .reduce() fixed it. Thanks anyways!

Comment: wrong argument-order in the map-callback. it's `.map( slide => $(slide).height() )`

Comment: In order for this solution to work, I need to remove 'index' argument from map, otherwise it throws me this exception:
"olhares.min.js?v=1:4 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'."

So in the end it looks like this:

`Array.from($('.comments-item.slick-slide.slick-active'))
.map( (slide) => $(slide).height() )
.reduce( (prev, next) => prev + next, 0 );`

Comment: And instead of the (a bit) bulky `Array.from($(selector))`, you can also write `$(selector).toArray()`, so this boils down to: `$('.items').toArray().map( el => $(el).height() ).reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0);`

Comment: My apologies. I didn't actually run this example. I came across same issue yesterday so I just knew what the solution was :). 
updated it with fix provided by @Andre Senra

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.items')
    .toArray()
    .map( (index,slide) => $(slide).height() )
    .reduce( (prev, next) => prev + next, 0 );
```

Thanks to @thomas for pointing this out.